# How to trigger a button click after a specific time?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I have a program with a button but I'd like to trigger that after a specific time. How do I do that? I have tried this code but there is no `ElapsedEventArgs` in my timer event.

```
static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 1 && DateTime.Now.Minute == 0)
    {
        // do whatever
    }
}
```

I also tried:

```
if (System.DateTime.Now.Minute == 35)
{
    btn_readAttLog.PerformClick();
    button2.PerformClick();
}
```

but it's not working. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Is it Web Application or Windows Form Application? Are you using Timer Control? Did you set Enabled property of the control to true? You need to use `Interval` property `Tick` event of the control...

Comment: It is Windows Form Application, Yes i set the property control Enabled = True and I set a interval of 10 seconds = 10000

Comment: Are you using the Tick event? Did you check if the proper event handler is associated with the event?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya thanks bro. you made me realize something it's working now.

Comment: Use the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, not the `System.Timers.Timer`. The event of the former (`Tick`) is raised in the UI Thread. The latter's is not. Move the code you have in the Buttons `Click` events to a method, so you can call that method from anywhere you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the better way of working with `DateTime.Now`.

```
var d = DateTime.Now;

if (d.Hour == 3 && d.Minute == 46)
{
     Console.WriteLine("good");
}
```

Comment: It's not working i dunno why. but when i try it with a new project it's working.

Comment: try to compile your project where this code doesn't work. let me know if you have any errors!